# Django creates incorrect MySQL LIKE statement

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, sql-like

I am using Django for an application that uses a simple filtering system. I want the filter to test if the title of my model contains a query string.

The code, stripped down, looks like this:

```
cards = Card.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

print cards.query
```

which returns the following query (again, unnecessary stuff is stripped):

```
SELECT [...] FROM `ygo_card_card`
WHERE `ygo_card_card`.`title` LIKE %dark%
```

Which returns no results, even though it should. When I run this query manually, I get

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%dark%' at line 1

If I wrap the `%dark%` part between apostrophes (`'%dark%'`) when running manually, it works as expected. It seems to me that Django creates an incorrect query. Is this a bug or something that I can control by settings?

Any search returns irrelevant results, because the related keywords are too generic.

I use Django 1.6.5 and MySQL 5.5.38, running on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the value of `.query` for the actual query that gets sent the database, it's not always a true reflection.

Comment: And how should I debug this then? The query is pretty simple and I am sure there is at least one model fulfilling the condition.

Comment: What is the value of `query`?

Comment: It's written in the post, right under the Python code.

Comment: @CosminStamate I mean the value of `query` variable passed into the `filter()`.

Comment: @alecxe, I am sorry. The value is `dark`.

Comment: @CosminStamate thanks, could you also show the `Card` model definition? Not sure, if it is relevant though.

Comment: @CosminStamate a better way is to look in `django.db.connection.queries` after you have executed the query. DEBUG needs to be on.

Comment: @alecxe, thank you for the interest, but I figured it out, see my response below.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, thank you, your comments lead me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The response is quite simple: I misinterpreted the problem.

The issue comes from an underlying problem: the MySQL `LIKE` statement is case-sensitive or insensitive depending on the collation and the Django filter used (`icontains` or `contains`) has no effect in the outcome. You can see this [bug ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9682) for more information.

As [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) pointed out, the `.query` property is not reliable, as the query is further processed by the database driver. This led me to believe that Django created a wrong query, while in fact it simply created a case-sensitive search that should have been case-insensitive, hence the lack of results.

In the end, the issue was resolved by changing the collation on columns, tables and the database.